# Not receiving output from Pandas from data.head(), but am receiving it from print of the same file

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Im trying to get better with Pandas, and start integrating a bunch of jobs into a json format so I can upload it into a jobboard Im working on for a bunch of people who have been laid off, but I dont understand this issue, it doesnt make any sense. Im following what appears to be exceptionally basic guides, using Visual Studio Code at the moment, and its returning the information as expected when I run the code from print(), but not from data.head().

The Tutorials:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-insert/

https://gokhanatil.com/2017/10/python-for-data-science-importing-csv-json-excel-using-pandas.html

Am I missing a module or something? I have Pandas installed, and it doesnt list additional modules required in either instance.

```
import pandas as pd   

# reading csv file 
data_CSV = pd.read_csv('test2.csv') 

# displying  dataframe - Output 1 
data_CSV.head()

print("============================================================================")

print(data_CSV)

# inserting column with static value in data frame 
#data_CSV.insert(2, "Team", "Any") 

# displaying data frame again - Output 2 
#data_CSV.head()
```

Code Output:

```
============================================================================
      pokemon   type
0   Bulbasaur  Grass
1     Ivysaur  Grass
2    Venusaur  Grass
3  Charmander   Fire
4  Charmeleon   Fire
5   Charizard   Fire
```

Comment: Do you think  `data_CSV.head()` not working ?  So need `print(data_CSV.head())` ?

Answer (score 1):

`data_CSV.head()` does not print anything. Rather it returns the head of the table (5 rows by default? unsure).

Change it to `print(data_CSV.head())` if you want to see the output.

Comment: I tried that, and it worked, but the outputs dont match. I assume the tutorial(s) are wrong?

This is my output:

      pokemon   type
0   Bulbasaur  Grass
1     Ivysaur  Grass
2    Venusaur  Grass
3  Charmander   Fire
4  Charmeleon   Fire
============================================================================
      pokemon   type
0   Bulbasaur  Grass
1     Ivysaur  Grass
2    Venusaur  Grass
3  Charmander   Fire
4  Charmeleon   Fire
5   Charizard   Fire

What does head do, or whats its intended to do?

Comment: @Fallenour .head(n=5) returns the first n-rows. That is a copy of the first n-rows is returned as a new dataframe. You can specify more or fewer rows as you need. So yes the output you are seeing is exactly what is expected. What did you try to do? Or rather how did you think .head() would work?

Comment: I honestly thought it would simply print all of the information out, acting a lot like cat does with linux. Thats good to know though, at least now I can read the lines, line by line, and I can see the output in real time as its updated.